# Counting a group of columns on google spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a couple of columns as shown below:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
1    12  4  1  
2     3  2  2  
3        7   
4     3  0     6
```

How would I be able to return a count of each column above so for example receive the result:

```
    A   B  C  D  E
1      12  4  1  
2       3  2  2  
3          7   
4       3  0     6
5 count:3  4  2  1
```

for each of the column. Im looking for a formula that would be able to do that in one cell(B5) returning a count for each of the columns, and avoid using fill handling as the data set is quite large

Comment: `count`, `counta`?

Comment: @findwindow been there, suggested that.  The OP wants it to fill across without using any of the regular fill methods, ie dragging, copying or using fill.  OP wants a formula in B5 that will automatically fill across all columns.

Comment: Oh, something like `3,4,2,1,` all in one cell (b5)?

Comment: @findwindow yea if possible

Comment: How many columns are we talking?

Comment: @findwindow about 30

Comment: Ok. That's manually doable. Just add `count`s. Edit: `=COUNT(B:B) & ", " & COUNT(C:C), etc` Edit2: er not sure what limits of google spreadsheet is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy, using Google Spreadsheet's functions:

```
=ArrayFormula(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(row(A1:A4)^0),--(len(A1:E4)>0)))
```

Or, if you want join them all:

```
=JOIN(", ",ArrayFormula(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(row(A1:A4)^0),--(len(A1:E4)>0))))
```

Comment: This is great but it does not count the `0` in C4 in the test data provided by the OP.

Comment: Thank you, @Scott Craner! I'll correct the answer.  `--(A1:E4<>"")` is to be changed to `--(len(A1:E4)>0)` . `Mmult` part was also incorrect.